# % width puts element outside container, same px width keeps it inside

Tags: css

I have a div that I am trying to place inside of another div.  The pink div is the container and the red div is mine.  My div contains an internal div that is 44px wide.  The css properties of my div are `float: right`, `text-align: center`, `box-sizing: border-box`, and `border-collapse: collapse`.  When I set `width: 44px`, I get the following result:

[image]

When I set `width: 15%`, however, the box floats to the edge of the screen instead of to the edge of the containing div.  No other property is being changed between these two pictures.

[image]

What is the explanation for this behavior?

JsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xU9RV/

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you could provide the HTML as well as more of the CSS (for the container div and more). The more the better. Also you could put it into a jsfiddle so we can see the problem live.

Comment: The innermost div is bigger than the 15% div, causing it to overflow out of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important aspect of how widths in percentage are working, is that they depend on the width of the parent element.

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;">
  <div style="float: right; width: 15%; background-color: pink;">
    <div style="width: 44px; height: 44px; background-color: red;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in your code here you set the first div to be 100px wide. The second div is set to 15% and as percentage is dependant on the parent width, it's only 15px wide. So when the third div comes with 44px width it will overflow the parent container and show as if it was half way outside the first div.

To get the same width of the percent as the pixel value, you have to use 44% of the 100px the parent is.

So when working with widths it's important to keep in mind that percentage are dependent on it's parents width.